# What do two moons signify in Goblin slayer anime?

Tags: goblin-slayer

In Goblin Slayer, I noticed sun is always one, but in night moon are two. Below is a picture from a scene:

[image]

My question is what is the significance of these two moons there ?

Comment: They aren't on Earth?

Comment: @pboss they are.

Comment: I don't think they are on Earth. The fact that there are two moons, that magic can be used, to name a few, prove that it is set in a fictional world.

Comment: @W.Are It's earth only. If you have watched the serial, Remember when priestess cast her spell, she starts with "O mother earth..."

Comment: O mother earth' could refer to earth as in 'soil'. I could be wrong but I think this can be resolved by looking at the raw version of the LN/manga to see if it really does refer to Earth as a proper noun when it says 'earth'.

Comment: @W.Are is right. In [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlnmHpxRyjQ) Priestess uses the word "chiboshi", which means something like mother goddess and earth goddess​. The word is written as 地母神, where 地 means earth or ground, 母 means mother and 神 means god.